One of the monitors is not working
I'm using a 4 monitor system and a couple of days ago everything was working great. After one of the computer reboots, the monitor on the DVI-D-0 output simply stopped displaying the image, displaying “no signal”. I booted from a live system and all 4 monitors showed the image in this case. On the main system, all monitors are defined in the settings, in inxi and nvidia-settings. It isn't problem in xorg or something cause it didn't work even when i boot just in tty without sddm.service.
Configuration:
Arch linux x86_64,
Kernel 6.9.7-arch1-1,
KDE Plasma 6.1.1,
CPU: i5-13600kf,
GPU: GTX 1080ti,
32Gb DDR4
Edit:
I tried to reinstall linux-base and it even do not work in emergency mode. Next, i changed my kde-plasma to i3wm.
xrandr output:
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6720 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1600x900+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 432mm x 240mm
   1600x900      60.00*+
   1920x1080     59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x480       59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+2880+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  75.00    59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x1024     75.02    72.00    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x768      59.87  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 connected 1920x1080+4800+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x1024     75.02    72.00    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x768      59.87  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  

I tried another advices from another questions about same theme and it didn't work. Advices like this:
xranrd --xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --off
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1600x900 --pos 1600x0


What does xrandr say when they are all connected?

It prints parameters of all 4 monitors

I found the reason of the problem. So, the new Nvidia drivers just do not give any image at DVI-D port for some reason or bug. I just deleted them and install mesa driver and, oh miracle, all 4 monitors works.
So, guys, if you have problems like mine, try install another drivers or previous version of yours.
